# Enum внутри другого enuma: какие способы решения задачи предпочтительнее?

Tags: c#, enum

**Задача:** Есть класс "Полёт" `Flight`, который имеет свойство определенного типа (для примера, пусть это будет тип "Этап" `Stage`). Количество `Stages` и их имена определены заранее, поэтому этот тип сразу хочется описать как `enum`. Т.е. теперь мы имеем такую структуру:

```
public enum Stage { Stage1, Stage2, Stage3 };

public class Flight
{
    //...
    public Stage FlightStage { get; set; };
    //...
}
```

Также необходимо, что для каждого `Stage` должен быть свой набор фаз полёта `Phase`. Их имена и количество тоже определены заранее. Т.е. их тоже хочется обернуть в `enum`. Хотелось бы видеть что-то подобное:

```
public enum Stage 
{ 
    enum Stage1
    {
        Phase1,
        Phase2
        //...
    },
    enum Stage2, 
    {
        PhaseA,
        PhaseB
        //...
    },
    //... 
};
```

Погуглил я вопрос на эту тему. Оказывается, в C# такое делать нельзя (если ошибаюсь, то поправьте).

**Вопрос:** Каким образом лучше всего описать такую структуру данных на языке C#? Я уверен, что уже придуман наилучший способ описания такой структуры данных.

UPD. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример.

Comment: Используйте классы и наследование

Comment: _в C# такое делать нельзя_ - да, нельзя

Comment: [возможно поможет ответ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/163987)

Comment: @АндрейNOP можете привести пример? потому как я с трудом представляю, как это можно хорошо сделать, избегая валидации строковых значений.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, например, вот https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx . Одно из библиотечных перечислений майки сделали в виде класса со статическими полями.

Comment: Ну как: `abstract class ЭтапПолета { }` `abstract class Этап1 : ЭтапПолета { }` `class Фаза1 : Этап1 { }` и т.д. Более того, если на ваш FlightStage завязана некая логика, использование enum может быть вообще вредно. Почитайте про паттерн Состояние

Comment: @АндрейNOP Теперь я понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @АндрейNOP шаблон State - это именно то, что я искал, благодарю!) Если хотите, можете оформить ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на FlightStage завязана некая логика, то использование enum здесь будет скорее даже вредно. Обратите внимание на шаблон проектирования **Состояние** (State), его реализация подразумевает, что этап полета становится классом (или интерфейсом) и инкапсулирует в себе всю логику, которая от него зависит:

```
abstract class ЭтапПолета
{
    // Набор методов
}

abstract class Этап1 : ЭтапПолета { ... }

class Фаза1 : Этап1 { ... }

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Как верно заметили в комментариях такое делать нельзя в стандартах C#.

Однако, как опять же заметили в комментариях этого можно добиться использованием классов.

`enum` ранее в природе вообще не существовало и он в большей степени является синтаксическим сахаром. По сути- это статический класс с константами.

В языках без `enum` принято делать класс со статическими полями константами.

Например, перечисление [форматов изображений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx) в библиотеке .NET реализовано именно так.